# MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE not Writing complete bytes to File

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, video-capture, mediastore

i am using **MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE** Intent to record video into custom Uri by **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT**. Here i am facing interesting issue in nokia Device. In Other device its working fine.

when i record video for example 10 seconds and play that file by going into custom recorded file path android default player play video for 9 seconds and then says can't play file. If i do not pass **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** then everything works fine and device default player play complete video. but i have a requirement to store Video in custom folder.

Its seem to me Camera app unable to write complete bytes in custom folder. how can i fix this issue. remember i am only facing this issue in Nokia G10 device

here is my code

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
        takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(activity!!.packageManager)?.also {
            takeVideoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
            takeVideoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileUri(activity!!, filePath))
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0)
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60)
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        }
    }


fun getFileUri(activity: Activity, filePath: File): Uri {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            filePath
        )
    else
        return Uri.fromFile(filePath)
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
    <files-path name="appfolderName" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="appfolderName" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="storage" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: `<files-path` You can only have that once.

Comment: `<external-files-path` You can only have that once.

Comment: var filePath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + filename + ".mp4").absolutePath